# Display Contents After Correct User Input

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm a beginner in web dev but I'm really good on the software end. I have some HTML to display text and a YoutTube Video on a webpage. But before this, the user must be prompted to input a value in a text box.

What I wanted is for the user to see a box with a submit button. The box will only accept one of 7000 unique entries. Once the user inputs one of the 7000 entires, only then the HTML/YouTube Video must be displayed. Otherwise the page can display a message saying: Retry, entry not recognized.

The webpage is running Wordpress with Motopress. Is there anyway I can do this with Custom fields to store the values or whichever way is easy and quick?

Comment: Where are you storing the correct entries and how secure / unhackable does this need to be?

Comment: The correct entries are stored in custom fields. I was thinking that I can maybe chose password protected but when I do that, the page is not displaying anything. And don't bother about it being too secure.